# Convert milliseconds into date in different timezones

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How to convert milliseconds in mm/dd/yyyy in different timezones.

I have a datepicker, when I press save, it saves the date in millisecond.
The saved millisecond should display date according to timezone date.

My Code:

```
var millisecond=1378792800000;
var date=new Date(millisecond);
var date_month = date.getMonth() + 1;
display_date = date_month + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear();
```

The date is differ in different timezones
When my timezone is India GMT then it is 09/10/2013
and when I change my timezone to US Mountain it change to 09/09/2013.

So how can I handle different timezone in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a third party script such as **[moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/timezone-offset/)** to make your life easier

Here is an example: **http://jsfiddle.net/cyxgJ/**

```
var ms = 1378792800000;
var date = new moment(ms);

// see <http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/timezone-offset/>
date = date.zone(120);

document.body.innerHTML = date;
```